# Details on cisco MDS series switches

Tags: switch

Hello I 'm new to CISCO  Switch world.

I 'm working as Clariion Admin and have have taken up the responsibilty to manage switches.Since,i am a novice i need little guidance on how to work on cisco switches.I know the Zoning (how zoning done on MDS 9000 series switches) part ,but would like to venture deep into the details on CISCO MDS series switches.

Like, the use of Port channels etc.

Will really appreciate if some one can help me with a link or place ( not the configuration guide) where in i can find details on concentrated more on the theory part .

Will appreciate the help.

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[THIS](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Cisco-MDS-Cookbook-Seth-Mason/dp/061517888X/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1265386282&sr=8-1) book is as good as any I've come across although you could do worse than going on some of the various MDS courses. MDS's aren't that straightforward but are very rewarding when you start to feel comfortable with them. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you go get a couple of older Cisco switches off ebay (or get your company to pay ;) so that you aren't learning on production equipment. It won't be exactly the same, but you will definitely get a handle on the basics of working with Cisco.

You might also want to check out [GNS3](http://www.gns3.net/)

A few good books to read:

- [The ICND Cisco Study Guides](http://search.barnesandnoble.com/CCNA-Certification-Library/Wendell-Odom/e/9781587200977/?itm=6&USRI=icnd)
- [Network Warrior](http://search.barnesandnoble.com/Network-Warrior/Gary-A-Donahue/e/9780596101510/?itm=1&usri=Network+Warrior)

Comment: Sorry to be a downer Zypher but this dude's into MDS *SAN* switches, not LAN stuff, really good links though and very kind of you - so definitely no minuses from me ok :)

Comment: @Chopper3: oops, back to the coffee pot for me! The next step is LAN Switching of course, i'm just putting him ahead of the game ;)

Comment: no problem mate, that said I reckon lan switching is WAY simpler than SAN/FC switching - I've been doing it for years and it does my head in completely sometimes.

Answer (score -1):

You can't just pick up a manual with the Cisco IOS, there is a lot of information that you need to know. It isn't as simple as just typing a command to do one function.

For example to configure a interface there's like 8 commands to do just to give a interface a ip address.

Comment: I appreciate your answers,but isn't there a way(link/book) I can learn them??

Comment: That isn't really an answer - and it's only 4 commands to assign an ip to an interface ( en; conf t; int <interface>; ip address <ip> )

Comment: @P858snake - MDS's don't run IOS though.